# Show $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(xu)}{u^2}du=\frac{\pi}{2}|x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I would like to show $$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(xu)}{u^2}du=\frac{\pi}{2}|x| \,\,\,\,\,\,(\forall x\in \mathbb{R}).$$If I ask whether the integral converges uniformly, of course $\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(xu)}{u^2}$ converges uniformly on $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for $\epsilon>0$, but I am having trouble finding a bound near $u=0$ which does not depend on $x$.

I've tried expressing the integrand as an integral in $x$ (hoping to then switch the order), without success. If I try differentiating underneath the integral with respect to $x$ I get $\frac{2\sin(xu)\cos(xu)u}{u^2}=\frac{2\sin(2xu)}{u^2}$, whose integral converges conditionally, I believe, which leaves me with no justification for differentiating under the integral.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x=0$, the statement clearly holds.

Start off with the substitution $w=ux$, $dw=x\,du$.  This gives (assuming $x$>0),
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(w)x^2}{w^2}\frac{du}{x}=x\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(w)}{w^2}\,dw
$$
On the other hand, if $x<0$, then we get
$$
x\int_0^{-\infty}\frac{\sin^2(w)}{w^2}=-x\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\sin^2(w)}{w^2}\,dw=-x\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(w)}{w^2}\,dw,
$$
since the function is even. Notice that the front term is precisely $\lvert x\rvert$ in either case!  So, all that is left is to compute the integral.